# Getting a "slice" of a linked-list in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, I have a structure that resembles a linked-list. Each node has a `prev` field for an `id` to the previous node, and I link them together using a `chain` relationship. There are some cases when a node is not part of this chain, ie, it's "prev" points to another node, but nothing points to it.. or only 1 node points to it.

I want to take a "slice" of this list, only including the nodes that are directly linked. ie, from the point of node A, back to node B, return all nodes in between.

This is what I have so far

```
match (fb {id: A}) - [:chain] -> (eb {id:B})
return fb
```

However, it returns no results... I think I need it to go recursive in some way, but I'm not sure how to indicate that. I've tried using :chain*, but this tends to process forever. I think I need a way to limit it..

How do I do this?

Comment: How big are you chains? Are there many paths between A and B?

Comment: @DaveBennett farily large.. 10K or more

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
MATCH (fb {id: A})-[:chain*1..10]->(eb {id:B})
RETURN fb
```

That should limit it to 10 levels.  You can change that if you like, obviously, but it affects performance

EDIT: Was just reading this guide to performance tuning:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/

One bit that caught my eye:

> If you’re using queries that will have a relatively large working set
>   (ie. will be traversing long paths, looking at lots of properties, or
>   collecting large sets of results in order to do sorting, etc) then
>   you’ll need a larger working heap. If you have small queries that do
>   very limited traversals and return small amounts of data, you need
>   less. Assume 1-2GB to start and tune from there

Comment: so there is no way (with fast query response) to take this to an arbitrary level? Or something like 1000 levels

Comment: Not that I know of for cypher.  For things like that I think you'd want to use java (or some java compatibility thing for another language like JRuby for Ruby).  You might also look into neo4j unmanaged extensions which would let you create an endpoint in Neo4j which returns the result you want

Comment: hmm.. I also have access to a numerical (incrementing) "height" field, which basically says where a node is at in the linked list.. I know I could use this with WHERE easy enough.. However, I'd need to exclude nodes that branch off from the list (ie, aren't actually connected to the ending node). Would that approach be at all easier?

Comment: It might help Neo4j filter down results, though I'm guessing those nodes which brach off have `height` values in the same range that you'd be looking for, right?  You might try changing `10` to `1000` in my example query and see if it performs well.  I assume you have a lot of branching off?  To branches go for long "distances"?

Comment: Yea, they'd have the same `height`... Branches should be pretty small, like less than 10 nodes... though I need to be able to function with them being potentially 100-200 nodes

Comment: Have you tries changing the limit from 10 to 100/1000/10000?  It might help.  I've found issues sometimes with increasing my limit, but if you're dealing with a relatively linear data set it might not be so bad.  You might want to make sure you have a timeout set, though: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/

Comment: Yea, I tried this and encountered extreme performance problems with it.. I'm going to try to see if there is a better way I can structure this data

Comment: Just made an edit on tuning memory which may be helpful